# Linking to an SSRS report and setting parameters in the URL

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I've got this block of code:

```
ErrorLogging.WriteLog(string.Format("Username = {0}, userkey = {1}, userID = {2}", CurrentUser.Username, CurrentUser.UserKey, CurrentUser.Username + CurrentUser.UserKey.ToString()));
ssrsRV.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
ssrsRV.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(SystemConfig.SSRSServerURI);
ssrsRV.ServerReport.ReportPath = report.REPORT ?? string.Empty;
ssrsRV.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("UserID", CurrentUser.Username + CurrentUser.UserKey.ToString()));
```

The first line just proves to myself that I've got valid information in the those variables.  The userID ends up being something like  "jsmith162e4aa1-d8d3-427b-bd3d-71b7f0307856"

ssrsRV is an `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer` object.

When I try and run this code I get this error message:

> The path of the item '/MyFolder/MyExampleReport.rdl~!@~!@' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath)

The exception is thrown by the `SetParameters` method, so I'm sure that's the problem, but I haven't tested not passing parameters at all.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?  What I should try next?

Comment: try setting ReportPath to "/MyFolder/MyExampleReport" (no extension). And what is ~!@~!@ in the report path?

Comment: Can you detail what is in the `report.REPORT ?? string.empty`? I wonder why you get the `.rdl`?

Comment: Its pulling the report path from the database.  I configured it with the .rdl so that's why that's there.  I'm a bit of a noob at this, so I randomly tried a few different things like that.

I don't know what the "~!@~!@" is, but it seems to be the source of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm dumb.

The code was perfect, the application was adding the "~!@~!@" to the report path in the database without displaying it to the user.  If I write a SQL statement to remove those characters from the report path in the database, it works perfectly.

Thanks,

Comment: I find it interesting the application adds those characters. :S

Comment: "Interesting".  I'd use a different word.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to declare the report parameter first:

```
ReportParameter[] RptParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
```

Then assign the parameter:

```
RptParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("UserID", CurrentUser.Username + CurrentUser.UserKey.ToString());
```

Then set the parameter:

```
ssrsRV.ServerReport.SetParameters(RptParameters);
```

See how this goes.

Comment: I tried this, but it had no affect.  The SetParameters Method has an overloaded method that takes a ReportParameter instead of a IEnumerable.